# Solutions of $x^{p^n}=x$ form a subfield $F\subset K$.

Tags: field-theory

$K$ is an algebraically closed field such that Char $K=p$. Show that the solutions of $x^{p^n}=x$ form a subfield $F\subset K$.

My Work:

$0$ is a solution and $0\in K$. Let $\alpha$ be a non zero root. Then $\alpha^{p^n-1}=1$. I want to show that $\alpha\in K$. But stuck in showing so. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that all roots are in $K$ follows from the fact that $K$ is algebraically closed. The fact that $F$ is a field follows from the fact that $(a+b)^{p^n}=a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}$ and similarly for multiplication. Trying to fill in the details is a good exercise I think.

Comment: K algebraically closed means any $f(x)\in K[x]$ has a root in $K$. How does it follow that all roots are in $K$?

Comment: @Mathi It's equivalent (by induction on the degree of the polynomial) that a field is algebraically closed iff every nonconstant polynomial splits into linear factors, i.e., the field contains *all* of its roots.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field#Equivalent_properties).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346934/is-abpn-equiv-apnbpn-pmodp-true

Answer (score 2):

Since char $K = p, K$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$ Now consider $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x] \subset K[x]$ and take the splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ inside $K.$

Answer (score 1):

K is algebraically closed and contains all roots of polynomials with coefficients in K.

$x^{p^n}-x=0$ has derivative $-1$ (mod $p$) so all roots are distinct. if $\alpha$  and $\beta$ are roots then the fact that
$$
(\alpha+\beta)^{p^n} \equiv_p \alpha^{p^n}+\beta^{p^n} \\
(\alpha\beta)^{p^n} \equiv_p \alpha^{p^n}\beta^{p^n}
$$
means the roots form a ring.

if $\alpha \ne 0$ then $\alpha^{p^n-1} \equiv 1$ so $\alpha$ has an inverse